# Entity Framework uses newsequentialid() for Guid Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

Using below code,

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // more properties here
}
```

I thought EF is using newguid(), but when I check database, I see the default value is newsequentialid()

Is this the default behavior of EF? Or it is because I'm using SQL Server 2017?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right, by the default `newsequentialid()` is used as a default value for GUID properties. `newsequentialid()` is recommended over `newid()` mostly because of performance considerations.

If you want to have `newid()` as default value you could achieve this by enabling migrations and specifying `defaultValueSql` in `CreateTable()`:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.UserProfiles",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true, defaultValueSql: "newid()"),
            Name = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

Comment: Sequential Guids are only sequential until the server is restarted! Is this correct?